# Leaflet Tooltips on GeoJSON multipolygons

Tags: polygon, leaflet

I'm currently using the `bindTooptip` function on a layer to bind a label to it.

One of my layers, however, consists of 2 Polygons that are within the same feature, using the array format:

```
[
  [
    [0.22, -0.26], [0.23, -0.25], [0.23, -0.26], [0.22, -0.26]
  ], 
  [
    [0.29, -0.273], [0.29, -0.26], [0.30, -0.26], [0.30, -0.27]
  ]
]
```

While I am able to automatically style both Polygons this way, adding a label will center it on the first one. I'm wondering if there's any way to bind a tooltip onto the 2nd one, or if I simply need to separate the polygons and make my own logic for them to be grouped as they currently are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to separate them. You only get one set of attributes for a multi-polygon feature, and you only get one label.